# TcpClient doesn't reveive all data

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpclient

I have a "messenger" application that works like this:
Client Sends Message to Server -> Server forwards Message to rest of the clients -> Clients read the message.

The server always receives the messages, but the clients do not.

Code that forwards the message to all clients (Server/TcpListener):

```
public static void SendToAll(TcpClient sender, string message)
{
   // Log the recieved message in the console
   Console.WriteLine(message);

   // Save the recieved message for new clients
   messageLog += message + "\n";

   byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
   foreach (TcpClient client in clients.Keys)
   {
      if (client == sender || clients[client] == "") continue;
      if (!client.Connected)
      {
         clients.Remove(client);
         continue;

      }

      NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
      stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
   }
}
```

Code that reads messages from the server (TcpClient):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (true)
{
   using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      Int32 bytes = 0;
      do
      {
         bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
      }
      while (stream.DataAvailable);
      Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
}
```

[Server (image attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL48f.png)

[Client1 (image attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUVAB.png)

[Client2 (image attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW3Sf.png)

Comment: `foreach (TcpClient client in clients.Keys)` - uhhh, is this code storing `TcpClient` objects as dictionary keys? If so, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I suspect your problem is that DataAvailable is returning false because your client has read and processed all the available data, even though not all of it has arrived yet, and asks for more before there is any ready, then gives up when it's told "none available" (because the next data is still in transit)

Comment: Using SignalR or some similar abstraction would probably make your life simpler, by the way

Comment: @Dai I am just fiddling around with TCP for the first time, so I'm not really taking security, performance, etc into account just yet.
If you can choose a better alternative, that'd be great though.

Comment: @CaiusJard I tried switching to this code:

`Int32 bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);


Console.WriteLine(message);`

and it's still the same

Comment: Well, ok.. but do you do that in a loop? Cos otherwise it can only read at most 1024 bytes, fewer if the network  is slow

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, it is in a `while (true)` loop.

Comment: @EliasV My remark about dictionary-keys has nothing to do with networking or TCP, just the fact that you generally should not use reference-types (except strings) as dictionary-keys because dictionaries depend on stable and _correct_ equality (and key hashes) to work. I admit that using reference-types (like `TcpClient`) _will work_ provided that they _do not_ override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` (so the dictionary uses object-identity), but as it's difficult to make sure it's best to avoid doing-so entirely (the only real exception being `String`, ofc).

Comment: @Dai, ah alright, thank you. I'll try to use something else.

Comment: @EliasV Dai's point may have merit but it is unlikely to be the cause of your complaint

Comment: @CaiusJard it may be it, but I haven't tested yet. Who knows. I'll update you guys.

Comment: @CaiusJard Update: it wasn't the problem, but I think I came to a solution! Switching the stream.read to ReadAsync(). I need to do some more testing though.

Comment: In and of iteself, I doubt that just swapping the read call out and leaving all your other code the same will make any difference. If a significant portion of it changes such that the entire read routine is behaving differently, then maybe..

Comment: Well, the read code is only 4 lines, so the chance is pretty significant I'd say. Will update tomorrow if it was the solution.

Comment: @CaiusJard changing the NetworkStream.Read() to ReadAsync() fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

The problem was probably caused because TCP is slow; not entirely finished with reading all the stream and already tasked with reading new data.

So I Switched

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (true)
{
   using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      Int32 bytes = 0;
      do
      {
         bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
      }
      while (stream.DataAvailable);
      Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
}
```

to

```
// ... Main() {
while (true) StartRead();
// ... }

public static async void StartRead(NetworkStream stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    Int32 bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, buffer.Length));
    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    Console.WriteLine(message);         
}
```